# YT gem on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api

I'm using the yt gem and I'm getting a server error :

[image]

I pasted in the curl request and it works fine from my local machine too.
The yt gem is not woking on a local server but works fine on a production server. Is the right gem to use to communicate with the youtube-api ?

Comment: Have you tried curl in terminal? Are you using any http proxy for browsing youtube on your browser? If that's the case, both curl and Yt won't work properly.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Yt gem? I have no problem with v0.25.24 on my localhost. What about youtube url or video id validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was an SSL error. I reinstalled RVM and updated open SSL with brew and everything worked fined after that.

Comment: Omg this saved me so much time. <3 u.

Comment: I wish I could give you extra points for answering your own question.

Comment: I am still having the same issue. How did you determine it was a SSL error? I was able to successfully update openssl and RVM but I still get this error while I am able to successfully make the `curl`. Any ideas?

Comment: I read the reponse of the curl request and determined it was a SSL error. How did you install open ssl ?